# Автоматическая генерация конструкторов, геттеров, сеттеров и т.п. для сущностей

Tags: php, doctrine2

Знаю о существовании `doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-annotations=GENERATE-ANNOTATIONS`, но проблема заключается в том, что эта команда удаляет все, что не связвнно с Doctrine, например аннотации `Symfony\Validator`, есть ли сторонние инструменты выполняющие аналогичную `doctrine orm:generate:entities --generate-annotations=GENERATE-ANNOTATIONS` задачу, но оставляя при этом существующий код полностю, не удаляя нечего?

Comment: А сгенерировать и дальше наследоваться от этих классов вас не устраивает? Генератор другой вы вряд ли найдёте. Если только сами допишите

Answer (score 0):

В symfony2 можно использовать `generate:doctrine:entities [путь к сущность]`.
У меня аннотация класса assert не удаляются.